# Javascript Callback Functions - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, download

I have two functions,

1) `download(uri, filename, callback)` -> Downloads an image to a specific location
2) `twitterPost(filename)` -> Tweets the image

I need to do this Asynchronously - so I call `twitterPost` after the image is done downloading, however I receive this error every time:

```
throw new Error('File path does not exist: ' + media);                                                                                                               
      ^                                                                                                                                                              
Error: File path does not exist: Imgs/18478-wrt1114.jpg
```

Now I understand that this is appearing because the image has not downloaded, however it doesn't make sense seeing that the callback function is called after the pipe is closed. Here is my code for both functions:

```
function download(uri, filename, callback) {
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body) {
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('end', callback);
    });
};
```

and

```
function twitterPost(filename) {

    var twitterRestClient = new Twitter.RestClient(
        // API KEYS AND STUFF HERE
    );

    twitterRestClient.statusesUpdateWithMedia(
        {
            'status': 'Test Tweet',
            'media[]': filename
        },
        function(error, result) {
            if (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error.message) }

            if (result) { console.log(result.text) }
    });
}
```

Here is my function call:

```
download(image, filename,twitterPost(filename));
```

Am I using callbacks incorrectly, or is there some other issue that I am not noticing causing this problem

Thank you for you help!

Comment: You're calling the function before calling `download`. It's not a callback, and it's not asynchronous - the file does not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I using callbacks incorrectly

Yes, you're not actually passing a callback *function*. You pass the result of immediately invoking `twitterPost(filename)` - which happens even before `download` is invoked, so there is no such file yet.

Use a function expression around this call, to get that function called by `download`:

```
download(image, filename, function(endEvent) {
    twitterPost(filename);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is due to the way you pass arguments to your function.

```
download(image, filename,twitterPost(filename));
```

check in `twitterPost(filename)` that your filename is as expected. I'm pretty sure it wont. That's because your twitterPost function is not called with this argument. It is called with :

```
request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('end', callback);
```

that is, no arguments. I'd do :

```
request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('end', function(){
  callback(filename);
});
```